# NodeJS sqlite3 how to return just the value from a column and not the column data

Tags: node.js, sqlite

```
router.get('/play/:song_id', async ctx => {
    try {
        const sql = `SELECT location FROM songs WHERE song_id = ${ctx.params.song_id} LIMIT 1;`
        const db = await sqlite.open(dbName)
        const data = await db.get(sql)
        await db.close()
        const newdata = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))
        console.log(newdata)
        ctx.response.type = 'mp3'
        ctx.response.body = fs.createReadStream(newdata)
    } catch (err) {
        ctx.body = err.message
    }
})
```

this is the output I get:

```
{ location: 'public/songs/Santeria.mp3' }
```

But I only want the `'public/songs/Santeria.mp3'` part (the value of the column).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change the line:

```
ctx.response.body = fs.createReadStream(newdata)
```

to

```
ctx.response.body = newdata.location
```